# How to load elevation event calendar on JQuery Modal dialog box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I'm developing project on rails and I have successfully implement the [elevation event calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) on my project but I try to implement it on jQuery modal dialog box but it doesn't work so Please can some one explain me how to load event calendar on JQuery Modal dialog box on rails 2.3.8 ?

Comment: PLease can you share your experience with me ?

Comment: Sorry to say it doesn't work for me so I left that idea in my project and load the event calendar on normal web page.